# How to subscribe to a channel after page load - ActionCable, DelayedJob

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have a controller with a background job to start ActionCable subscribtion:

```
  def result
    LinkBroadcastJob.perform_later(links)
  end
```

It performs this action to stream links:

```
  def perform(links)
      links.each do |link|
          ActionCable.server.broadcast "link_channel", html: render_link(link)
      end
  end
```

I have a view with a div id="here" in a layout.

In my file javascript/channes/link.coffee.js it should append all links to the div.

```
  App.link = App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "LinkChannel" },
    received: (data) ->
        $("#here").append(data.html)
```

The problem with this code is that the subscription is starting before the page is fully loaded - therefore the first links are not displayed and are missing.

I could solve it with delayed job with some set time (5 secs) but this wouldn't be the best experience and I don't know how fast it could take to user to load the full page. I tried to do also with $(document).load before it creates the subscription but it didn't work.

What is the best way to execute the subscription once the div tag is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your client side code inside a `turbolinks:load`:

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
   App.link = App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "LinkChannel" },
     received: (data) ->
         $("#here").append(data.html)
```

Comment: Would this help ensure the subscription is listening by the time the broadcast is received? I'm having a similar issue where I start a background job when I navigate to a new route, and the background job broadcasts before the page/js is loaded and ready to receive the message.

Comment: No I don't think it would. The best way to **ensure** it, is to send a request from the client side.
Also, if your background job finished before the client side rendering, it's probably better if you make a synchronous call and send the data with the server response

Comment: That makes sense. In my case I think it would make most sense to make a request to the client side as the job _could_ take up to 5 minutes. But I agree that if it's consistently that fast, doing the work synchronously would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I would advice against using ...

`Query(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->`

...as this is already accomplished on startup. This is what I did to resolve this:

Going back to your javascript/channes/link.coffee.js...
...actually, rename that to javascripts/channels/link.coffee  (-_^)

You have a `recieved:` method as shown below:

```
App.link = App.cable.subscriptions.create "LinkChannel",
  received: (data) ->
      $("#here").append(data.html)
```

Although you didn't mention it, you should have a method to broadcast a message/request to the server. Let's call it `refresh:` for now, and let's assume when I call `refresh:` this will eventually broadcast your code back to the client where `received:` will be called to pick up your new data:

```
App.link = App.cable.subscriptions.create "LinkChannel",
  received: (data) ->
      $("#here").append(data.html)

  refresh: ->
    @perform 'refresh'
```

Now, `recieved:` is a callback, but there are two more that are helpful here. Those are `connected:` and `disconnected:`. These are called when the channel is **connected** and **disconnected** respectively. Let's add this to the code:

```
App.link = App.cable.subscriptions.create "LinkChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
      $("#here").append(data.html)

  refresh: ->
    @perform 'refresh'
```

Ready now, we are going to get your code to load on startup.

So, instead of utilizing `jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->` as a wrapper, or any other which way, we are going to call the `refresh:` method once the channel has ....**connected**.

```
App.link = App.cable.subscriptions.create "LinkChannel",
  connected: ->
    App.link.refresh()

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
      $("#here").append(data.html)

  refresh: ->
    @perform 'refresh'
```

If you have any questions or concerns, don't hesitate to ask :)